# Gstreamer qmlgl plug-in enable via Yocto

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, bitbake

I would like to use qmlgl plug-in (qmlglsink, qmlglsrc) in my application, but it is not available in the image.

Also, my environment is ARM-based board - Phytec_nunki.

`gst-inspect-1.0 | grep qml` does not receive any result.

I use Yocto for building images. As I understand from this [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/qmlgl/index.html?gi-language=c) - qmlgl is located in "GStreamer Good Plug-in" bunch, but it is not enables by default.

I inspected the sources of gstreamer which is downloaded by Yocto - the files with "qmlgl" are there. So I guess I have to enable it in some config file.

I tried to add

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
gst-plugins-good-qmlgl\
"
```

into my local.conf file. Bitbake was executed successfully but the plug-in was not appeared.

So, does anyone have an idea for solving it?

Comment: tried to use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gst-plugins-good-qmlgl"`?

I don't use CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL, I find IMAGE_INSTALL more friendly to extend.

Comment: @CleitonBueno hi, thanks for reply. I tried to use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gst-plugins-good-qmlgl"` and  `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-qmlgl"`, but I got the error `* opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'gst-plugins-good-qmlgl'.`

Comment: Does compilation work?
See which error is generated in the log.do_install file and insert here.

Comment: @CleitonBueno Looks like compilation is fine. [Here](https://pastebin.com/AxcE3qrc) is a full reply from bitbake. And [here](https://pastebin.com/VELcRUbU) is that log file from bitbalke's reply.

Comment: I reviewed gst-plugins-good, and `qmlgl` seems to be a package that is included when enabling `gst-plugins-good` with support for qt5, which by default is disabled.
You must enable it, add the dependency layers(meta-qt5) for it to be installed. Look [link1](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.14.4.bb?h=thud#n73) [link2](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/1.16/meson_options.txt#L67) [link3](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/1.16/ext/qt/meson.build#L154)

Comment: @CleitonBueno I have the `meta-qt5` layer which is enabled qt5 for gstreamer in it's `recipes-multimedia` directory. I have tried to add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gst-plugins-good-qmlgl"` to my `local.conf`. Without any result. Should I add new `gst-plugins-good%.bbappend` file in `recipes-multimedia` with something inside, to enable `gst-plugins-good` and `qmlgl`? Sorry for a long response

Comment: @UncleSav Did you resolve this issue "opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'gst-plugins-good-qmlgl". I have run into the same error. Did you find a fix? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UncleSav using your own layer, do:

Example your layer is meta-xpto.

`meta-xpto/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_%.bbappend`

Inside the .bbappend add:

```
inherit qmake5_paths

PACKAGECONFIG[qt5] = '--enable-qt \
--with-moc="${OE_QMAKE_PATH_EXTERNAL_HOST_BINS}/moc" \
--with-uic="${OE_QMAKE_PATH_EXTERNAL_HOST_BINS}/uic" \
--with-rcc="${OE_QMAKE_PATH_EXTERNAL_HOST_BINS}/rcc" \
,--disable-qt,gstreamer1.0-plugins-base qtbase qtdeclarative qtbase-native'

PACKAGECONFIG_append = "qt5"
```

With this change, we inform gstreamer1.0-plugins-good that we want to compile with the qt flag and inform the necessary dependencies.

Comment: I did it, but nothing new appears. I have tried to use `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep qml` - without any result. And also checked for `src` elements manually

Comment: Which branch is using the Yocto Project?

Comment: It is a 'rocko' one

Comment: Okay, do you have a meta-xxx layer? Need extra customizations.

Comment: I have the next bunch of layers `meta-gstreamer1.0  meta-openembedded  meta-qt5   meta-yogurt meta-nodejs meta-phytec meta-rauc  poky`

Comment: Create your own layer and make the changes I mentioned above.

Comment: Wow, it works! I have removed previously added data from `local.conf` and following your advice - added new layer. Everything nice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @UncleSav nice! ;)

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not work for Gstreamer 1.16

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you are using i.MX8 with newer BSPs especially with 5.x Linux kernel, the packageconfig option should be:

```
QT5WAYLANDDEPENDS = "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "wayland", "qtwayland", "", d)}"

PACKAGECONFIG[qt5] = "-Dqt5=enabled,-Dqt5=disabled,qtbase qtdeclarative qtbase-native ${QT5WAYLANDDEPENDS}"

PACKAGECONFIG_append = "qt5"
```